# Seperate Consoles for Client and Server (Java RMI)

Tags: java, debugging, console, rmi

I am writing a client-server application using Java RMI.

Now, my question is I have multiple clients and a server, to see some communication, I have System.out.println statements (SOPs) in both client and servers, but I see all the outputs on just one console, is there a way to view them separately?

To clarify it further let me give you a simple example,

```
**Server**
void callServer(){
System.out.println("Server is called");
}


**Client**
void callClient(){
System.out.println("Client is called");
server.callServer();
}


**Simulator**  
main(){ 
//create RegistryServer
//create server instance
//create client instance
System.out.println("Sim Started");
client.callClient();
}
```

**OUTPUT of Sim**
Sim Started
Client is called
Server is called

**Desired Output**
`Sim Console:
Sim Started`

`Client Console:
Client is called`

`Server Console:
Server is called`

Is it possible?

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to pipe all output to one single place and preface the start of the written line with which program is doing the writing?  Or do you want the output to be written in separate locations?

Comment: No, I want to open three windows/consoles and each should show their SOPs...

Comment: pls clarify the setup you want: how many processes, how do they communicate? how many consoles, what should be in them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the client and server separated in different applications or are you running them both from one.  If you have them separated you can just run them each in separate terminals and writing to standard out would print the output of each application to its own terminal.

Comment: Running separated would give me different consoles but is there a way to have separate consoles using just one application?

Comment: does that one application acts as both the client and the server, but with RMI calls from/to itself?